# Android: Can't make ListView full size

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to make ListView full-screen size, but every time in my scroll view I can see just one item from ListView. 
There is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- progress -->
    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/login_progress" style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/main_form" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/countriesList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

That's how it looks:

[image]

How do I want to make it look:

[image]

I can't achieve this without harcode height of ListView.

Comment: 2 things; 1. your `listview` should always be `wrap_content` and your parent linearlayout should be `match_parent`, and 2. you should NOT be wrapping your listview in a scrollview. If you want nested scrolling you should be using recyclerview

Comment: @tyczj thank you for your advice. I am deleted scroll view :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put ListView inside ScrollView very bad idea. Try to not do it

```
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/countriesList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

it because in your top `LinearLayout` use `padding`. so, you can delete the all `padding`

so, it should be like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- progress -->
    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/login_progress" style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/main_form" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/countriesList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```